# VUE3 Data, props and v-if wont work together?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component called Filter, the parent sends a prop called showFilters. the value of showFilters is ['plaats']. In the Filter component there is a data object called filters. The value of this Object is.

```
data: function() {
    return {
        filters: {
            plaats: {
                title: 'Plaats',
                label: 'Plaats_Naam',
                key: 'Plaats_Id',
                type: 'default',
                active: true,
            }
        }
    }
},
```

in the html part of the Filters component i do this:

```
<div v-for="key in showFilters" v-if="filters[key].active" class="col py-8" @mouseover="log(filters[key]);">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

I get a error when doing this because filters[key] is undefined which is weird because when i remove the v-if the log works with the right data.

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: What is the value of `key` when you log that? I'm assuming there is a reason to not just do `key.active`?

Comment: When i log key it returns "plaats" as expected.
key.active wont work. Basically what i am doing is that the prop showFilters tells me to show which filters. So i foreach a simple array example:['place','type','prices'] and then check if the filter is active according to the data and use the values from the data filters.

I hope this clears it up a bit but probarly not :*(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `v-if` and `v-for` in the same element, separate `v-for` in another element like the virtual one `template` (not the root `template`) and in the `v-if` check also `filters[key]` :

```
<template v-for="key in showFilters">
 <div  v-if="filters[key] && filters[key].active" class="col py-8" @mouseover="log(filters[key]);">
    <h1>test</h1>
 </div>
</template>
```